# Casting not working from Android.Views.View to my custom View returning NULL

Tags: c#, xamarin, view, drawing, android-canvas

Extending a View in order to draw with a finger this is the the code I used.

```
public class DrawingView : View
{
// DO: ALL THE LOGIC
}
```

I have a View element in the Main.xaml file. On the MainActivity my code looks like this

```
drawingView_canvas = FindViewById(Resource.Id.drawingview_canvas) as DrawingView;
```

I'm getting a null on my drawingView_canvas. If I'm not mistaken by following the inheritance teachings I shouldn't be getting a null.

What's wrong with my casting?

Comment: are you sure that FindViewById is not returning a null?  Try it without the cast to verify.

Comment: Without doing casting I do get a View object.

Comment: @VictorAChavez Add the AXML that you are using to define your DrawingView